# SOLR How to highlight only multi term matches in a multi valued field

Tags: solr, highlighting

I have a multivalued cathegory field and these cathegories can have multible terms,
e.g. cathegory={"foo","foo-123", "foo-456"}

when I search for "foo-45" only the last cathegory "foo-456" should be highlightet, but instead the string "foo" will be highlightet in all three cathegories.

Which Highlighter can I use and how can I configer it to highlight only matches with all query terms matching?

This is my definition of the field and its type:

```
<field name="cathegory_field" type="cathegory_field_type" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="cathegory_field_type">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: This might be due to the field's analysis. Would you mind to share the field type of the field?

Comment: I added the field and its type to the question above

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it in my machine, **WordDelimiterFilterFactory** creates two tokens (foo and 456).

In my opinion, one thing you could do is removing **WordDelimiterFilterFactory** from the query analysis.

Another solution is to use another field for highlighting; where you do not use **WordDelimiterFilterFactory**. Below is a simple definition:

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="text_cat_hl">
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Then create a new field:

```
<field name="cat_hl" type="text_cat_hl" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

You need to copy the content of category_field to it:

```
<copyField source="cathegory_field" dest="cat_hl"/>
```

Lastly, you issue a query like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection1?select?q=cathegory_field:foo-456&hl.q=cathegory_hl:foo-456
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that I would find nothing when i search for "456 foo" or "foo_456" with underscore.

Maybe there is a possibility to retern only results for the multi valued field when all query terms match.